# why does my bootstrap modal not open?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have defined a bootstrap 3 modal in my code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalTmpl">
    <div class="modal show">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button ng-click="close()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="false">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <modal></modal>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
  </div>
```

This is my angular code:

```
  app.directive('modal', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'modalTmpl',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
      self.element = element;
      scope.close = function() {
        $log.info('close!');
        var modal = self.element.find('.modal');
        //debugger;
        modal.removeClass('show');
      }

    },
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {

    }
  };


var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

  };
};
```

When I click on open me it does not show the modal: ( Could it be the wrong bootstrap.css reference or something else?

plunkr :http://plnkr.co/edit/RhaUdB?p=preview

Comment: Your `open()` function has no code in it so indeed your modal will not open.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this by assigning `modalTmpl` id to your model

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTmpl">Open me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your modal template:

```
<div modal="isProductShowing" close="hideFullProduct()" options="productModalOptions">
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.isProductShowing = false;

$scope.currentFullProduct = null;

$scope.productModalOptions = {
    backdropFade: true,
    dialogFade:true
};

$scope.showFullProduct = function (productId) {
    $scope.isProductShowing = true;
    $scope.currentFullProduct = _.findWhere($scope.products, { id: productId });
}
```

Then you have to trigger the `showFullProduct` function from the main template:

```
<li ng-click="showFullProduct(product.productId)">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of issues with this code.

First, your ModalDemoCtrl is not defined. Second, your open function is not defined. I move the button the MainCtrl to show how it can works. And declare open function to set the show to true which will be used in ng-show directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/uP3xB7?p=preview

```
 <div type="text/ng-template" ng-show="show" id="modalTmpl">
   <!-- Modal box -->
 </div>

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.show = true;
  };
```